# Android: NullPointerException 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()'

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, textview, ros

I'm new to android programming and I'm having a problem with my codes. Can anyone help me or point out the cause of my error because I'm not really sure why it's giving me a NullPointerException when its a text view or if that is possible.

LogCat:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.app.rosbridge.MainActivity$2$1.run(MainActivity.java:133)
```

Here is the code for that line:

```
   current.setText(String.format("%.4f%s", batteryStateData.msg.current * Math.pow(10, 6), "A"));
```

But when i run my app my voltage is setting null and here is the code for the voltage:

```
   voltage.setText(String.format("%.4f%s", batteryStateData.msg.voltage, "v"));
```

Here is the full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private TextView voltage, current, percentage, status;
private SubscribedData<BatteryState> batteryStateData;
private RosbridgeListener rosbridge;
private boolean subscribed = false;
private boolean advertised = false;

/** Indicates that Lint should ignore the specified warnings for the annotated element. */
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);

    Button settings_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_btn);

    voltage = findViewById(R.id.voltage_txt);
    current = findViewById(R.id.current_txt);
    percentage = findViewById(R.id.percentage_txt);
    status = findViewById(R.id.status_txt);
    connectButton = findViewById(R.id.connect_btn);

    batteryStateData = new SubscribedData<>();
    final Type batteryStateType = new TypeToken<SubscribedData<BatteryState>>() {
    }.getType();


    // ROSBRIDGE protocol allows access to underlying ROS messages and services as serialized JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) objects
     WebSocket protocol communicates to a server for the connection from a user's web browser

    //A connection to the rosbridge thru the IP address of the robot from the socket
    rosbridge = new RosbridgeListener("ws://10.24.204.231:9090");
    rosbridge.setOnDataReceivedListener(new RosbridgeMessageListener() {

        // a running thread that when the connection is made the data of the topic will serialize and deserialized java objects to (and from) JSON. @param msg

            @Override
            public void onDataReceived(final String msg) {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            batteryStateData = new Gson().fromJson(msg, batteryStateType);
                            voltage.setText(String.format("%.4f%s", batteryStateData.msg.voltage, "v"));
                            current.setText(String.format("%.4f%s", batteryStateData.msg.current * Math.pow(10, 6), "A"));
                            percentage.setText(String.format("%.2f%s", batteryStateData.msg.percentage, "%"));
                            status.setText(String.format("%s", PowerSupplyStatus.values()[batteryStateData.msg.powerSupplyStatus]));
                        }
                    });

                    Log.d("B9T", String.format("Received data: %s", msg));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (!subscribed) {
                 rosbridge.Subscribe("/battery", "sensor_msgs/BatteryState");
                 subscribed = true;

            connectButton.setText("Disconnect");

              } else {

                rosbridge.UnSubscribe("/battery");
                subscribed = false;
            connectButton.setText("Connect");

      }
          }
    });
```

Comment: `batteryStateData.msg.current ` is null

Comment: Check if batteryStateData.msg.current is null.

Comment: @SanilKhurana sorry like I mentioned I'm new. how do i do that?

Comment: @RexJohnMabunga A very easy and basic way to do that would be just to print the value of batteryStateData.msg.current in logcat. You can do that by 
Log.d('MyActivity', batteryStateData.msg.current);

Answer (score 1):

Everytime when you are setting the text to textview, you must need to check if it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

You can check null before you set text on textview like the following.

```
 @Override
 public void run() {
     batteryStateData = new Gson().fromJson(msg, batteryStateType);

     // check null before set text or calculate something
     if(batteryStateData.msg.current != null){
         current.setText(String.format("%.4f%s", batteryStateData.msg.current * Math.pow(10, 6), "A"));
     }
     // you can check belows like above

     voltage.setText(String.format("%.4f%s", batteryStateData.msg.voltage, "v"));

     percentage.setText(String.format("%.2f%s", batteryStateData.msg.percentage, "%"));
     status.setText(String.format("%s", PowerSupplyStatus.values()[batteryStateData.msg.powerSupplyStatus]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check weather your created class with **GSON** is not null

and then check class fields values  is not null or 0.

```
batteryStateData = new Gson().fromJson(msg, batteryStateType);
if (batteryStateData != null) {

    if (batteryStateData.msg.voltage!=0)
        voltage.setText(String.format("%.4f%s", batteryStateData.msg.voltage, "v"));

    if (batteryStateData.msg.current!=0)
        current.setText(String.format("%.4f%s", batteryStateData.msg.current * Math.pow(10, 6), "A"));

    if (batteryStateData.msg.percentage!=0)
        percentage.setText(String.format("%.2f%s", batteryStateData.msg.percentage, "%"));

    if (batteryStateData.msg.values !=null)
        status.setText(String.format("%s", PowerSupplyStatus.values()[batteryStateData.msg.powerSupplyStatus]));

}
```